# How to emit real random particles

Tags: animation, particles

I'm working on a sort of idea that you can make an unique 'drawing' by downloading this blendfile, run the animation and get a truely unique drawing. Key of the concept is that designing needs no skill or knowledge.

**Problem:** I created a 'drawing machine' that emits random particles (*size* and *life*) and paints the canvas by using *dynamic paint*. But everytime I play the animation the exact same drawing comes out.

Of course I could use *seed*, but it will contradict the concept.

[image: The Drawing Machine and canvas]

Comment: typically seeds are initialized with a clock based value to garantee a new random set at every runtime. Ex: `seed = int( time.time() )`.

Are you setting any seed at the moment?

Comment: In PC we have "[pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)". It's very near to random generator, but it not relay random. In PC very difficult to get "true" random numbers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **Drivers** to get "random" **Seed** in **Particles** settings.

> As @Crantisz pointed you can just paste `#int( 99 * noise.random() )`
>   as a **Seed** value and **Driver** will be automatically added.

**Long way:**

1. Right click on **Seed** and **Add Driver** > **Manually Create Later (Single)**.
2. Go to **Graph Editor** and switch to **Drivers mode**.
3. In **Drivers** tab paste this expression: `int( 99 * noise.random() )`
4. **Update Dependencies**.

Now every time you open Blender Seed value will be different.

[image: settings]

Comment: I want to note, that you can do same thing just by entering `#int( 99 * noise.random() )` as seed value: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOKuX.gif

Comment: @Crantisz nice one! The result is the same but amount of steps is hugely reduced. Is the `#` symbol shortcut for adding Driver? I wasn't aware of this method.

Comment: and also, you can edit this driver without Graph Editor

Comment: @Crantisz very cool! Can you point to the part of the documentation that describes what this is all about?

Comment: This helps a lot, but is there a way to work around the disabled auto-run? It make it less automatic.

Comment: @jspr Auto Run is disabled by default due to security reasons. Auto execution of Python scripts could be harmful. You can turn it of in User Preferences > File > Auto Execution and check Auto Run Python Scripts.

Comment: The art project could code up that each time a red ball collides with a blue ball, a database gets updated, and a random file on the computer gets deleted :-}

Comment: @ajwood I've found it in the docs: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/introduction.html#adding-removing look for "Expression" paragraph.